# sending more than 20 bytes through bluetoothle plugin in ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy

I tried writeQ function to send more than 20 bytes but it didn't work for me. of course I think i did sth wrong here is my send function:

```
$scope.sendText = function (inputText) {
        var bytes = bluetoothle.stringToBytes(inputText);
        var encodedString = bluetoothle.bytesToEncodedString(bytes);
        if (inputText.length < 20) {
          bluetoothle.write(
            function (result) {
              alert("data transmitted" + JSON.stringify(result));
            },
            function (error) {
              alert("data transmission failed" + JSON.stringify(error));
            },
            {
              value: encodedString,
              service: $scope.sendCharService.serviceId,
              characteristic: $scope.sendCharService.uuid,
              type: "noResponse",
              address: $scope.deviceId
            }
          );
        }
        else {
          bluetoothle.writeQ(
            function (result) {
              alert("data transmitted" + JSON.stringify(result));
            },
            function (error) {
              alert("data transmission failed" + JSON.stringify(error));
            },
            {
              value: encodedString,
              service: $scope.sendCharService.serviceId,
              characteristic: $scope.sendCharService.uuid,
              type: "noResponse",
              address: $scope.deviceId
            }
          );
        }
      }
```

the if statement block works perfectly but the else no!
what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with this framework, but `type: "noResponse"` looks suspicious. If this is a code for (GATT) **Write Without Response** it will not work for more than 20 bytes, which is the purpose of `writeQ()`.

The correct procedure to use is **Write Long Characteristic Values**.

Comment: Actually the ATT Write Command which is behind Write Without Response will work up to `ATT_MTU-3` bytes. It's true that `ATT_MTU` starts by default with 23, but it's likely going to be higher after MTU exchange.

Comment: @BogdanAlexandru Are you talking about long MTUs? It is not always supported.

Comment: @EirikM the problem is that the only Characteristics which I have is "write", "write with out response" , "read" and "notify"

Comment: You need to check which features are supported by the framework and what version of Bluetooth is used. What you want is not necessarily supported, although specified by the standard.